# How to stop a system service?

Tags: android, android-service

I want to know how to stop a system service using my app in android, I'm not talking here about stopping a Service Class that exists inside my app, I'm taking about stopping a System Service like (**Bluetooth**, **Mailing**, **Alarm**, **WiFi**, .....etc) I tried to make it like the following but nothing stopped:

```
    stopService(new Intent(Service.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE));
```

Comment: It is not possible to stop system service.To customize system service go for AOSP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know how to stop a system service using my app in android,

In the UI of your app, you ask the user to completely power down their phone. If your app is a system app (i.e., installed on the `/system` partition, such as a pre-installed app), you may be able to power down the device yourself.

What developers perceive as a "system service" is merely an API to a core OS process. SDK developers do not have control over those processes.

Comment: If you had root, how could you stop a system service? For example, the usb service.

Answer (score 0):

with root shell,

```
adb shell am stop-service your-service
```

To disable the service permanently, you should remount and change the system files to modify related .rc file.